# Getting element width with compass

Tags: compass-sass, sass

Is there any way to get a *predefined* element with with compass(CSS Framework)?

**Let's say i have:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="class-1">foo</li>
    <li class="class-2">foo</li>
    <li class="class-3">foo</li>
</ul>
```

**What i want outputted is:**

```
ul > li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 50%;
}

ul > li.class-1 { width: 20px; margin-left: -10px; }
ul > li.class-2 { width: 26px; margin-left: -8px; }
ul > li.class-3 { width: 24px; margin-left: -12px; }
```

**If at all possible, I imagine I would have to do something like:**

```
ul > li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 50%;

    &.class-1 { width: 20px; }
    &.class-2 { width: 16px; }
    &.class-3 { width: 24px; }        

    @for $i from 1 through 3 {
        .class-#{$i} { margin-left: $item-width / 2; }
    }
}
```

But `$item-width` naturally isn't defined. Is there any way to calculate it in the case described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to reference a *predefined* element, as there are no predefined elements... In other words all elements are defined by you.

So the easiest way around this is create a mixin with includes as follows

```
@mixin counter($num) {
    width: $num+px; margin-left: - $num/2+px; 
}

ul < li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 50%;

    &.class-1 { @include counter(20); }
    &.class-2 { @include counter(16); }
    &.class-3 { @include counter(24); }
}
```

Hope this still helps someone as I notice it is quite old.